# SQL script is not working as intended: how to use an aggregate in a virtual column to order the results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM `npt_articles` WHERE (date_discovered >= 1464534366 AND
           date_discovered <= 1464534366 AND
                      npt_site_id = 4 AND
                      (@total_social := (comments_html + fb_total  + google_plus_one + pinterest + linked_in ) + 0.0) >
                      865.0 AND
                      http_status_code = 200) ORDER BY @total_social DESC;
```

It works but no where near as intended.

`total_social` is the aggregate value of other named fields of the same row (record, object, etc.) which is then compared against a number  which is injected into the query string. I want to also use this aggregate in a virtual column to then be used to order the results.

I tried this but I'm not sure if this is the way to go:

```
SELECT *, @total_social := (comments_html + fb_total  + google_plus_one + pinterest + linked_in ) + 0.0 FROM `npt_articles` 
WHERE (date_discovered >= 1464534366 AND
                      npt_site_id = 4 AND
                      @total_social >
                      865.0 AND
                      http_status_code = 200) ORDER BY @total_social DESC;
```

I think what I want is something like this:

```
SELECT *, ((comments_html + fb_total  + google_plus_one + pinterest + linked_in ) + 0.0) as total_social  FROM `npt_articles` WHERE (date_discovered >= 1464534366 AND
                      npt_site_id = 4 AND
                      total_social >
                      865.0 AND
                      http_status_code = 200) ORDER BY total_social DESC;
```

The only issue is that MySQL Workbench says `total_social` doesn't exist.

I've tried using a CTE like this:

```
WITH inner_table AS (
    SELECT 
        ((comments_html + fb_total + google_plus_one + pinterest + linked_in) + 0.0) AS total_social
    FROM
        `npt_articles`
)
select * FROM inner_table
WHERE
    (date_discovered >= 1464534366
        AND npt_site_id = 4
        AND total_social > 865.0
        AND http_status_code = 200)
ORDER BY total_social DESC;
```

like in "[Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause/8370216#8370216)" but MySQL Workbench won't accept it because it doesn't like the `WITH` at that position, which I know now isn't supported by MySQL.

Comment: No doubt, with sample data and desired results someone else could figure out what you actually intend.

Comment: you do NOT need a variable for this: `select ... WHERE ((comments_html+...+linked_in) > 865))`

Comment: then how would I pass it to to ORDER BY? plus It doesn't exist outside of the row query which is why I'm doing it outside of the query. I think [virtual columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/) might be what I'm after.

Comment: @MarcB Im guessing the OP is using the variable so as he doesn't have to re-write the line in the order by clause. Personally I would have created a variable in the select clause like he has in the second version. I'm with Gordon on this, we need some sample data (or the site the data is being pulled from, I'm guessing he's using google scholar or something), and what he expects, and what he's getting.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so the solution was to use the `HAVING` clause which I found from "[How to use a temp column in the where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630815/why-cant-i-use-a-temp-column-in-the-where-clause/630836#630836)", which I think is basicly a `WHERE` clause that happens after a `SELECT`.

Now my SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT *, 
       (comments_html + fb_total + google_plus_one + pinterest + linked_in) + 0.0 AS total_social FROM `npt_articles` WHERE (
  date_discovered >= 1464534366 
  AND 
  npt_site_id = 4 
  AND 
  http_status_code = 200 
) 
HAVING total_social > 865.0 ORDER BY total_social DESC;
```

Now it does the query, does the select, calculates the `total_social` column and then does a second query using `total_social` and then orders by `total_social` in descending order.